# pyvis - selection and filtering menu support in UTF-8

Tags: python, utf-8, vis.js, pyvis

The [newly added functionality of Pyvis](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/tree/experimental) allows to filter and select nodes within a graph. This functionality provides for great use in medium-sized networks (although some may have several hundred nodes).
Unfortunately, [it appears that UTF-8 texts are having a problem](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/issues/173).
The selection menu does not display words that contain UTF-8 characters, such as Hebrew and Arabic words. But, and this surprises me, the filtering tool worked. Perhaps there is a nuance in the way they represent the characters that cause this inconsistency.
Here is a mini example that can be used to reproduce the bug:

The first case (selection):

```
from pyvis.network import Network

net = Network(height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white",
                  select_menu=True)
net.add_nodes(['אברהם', 'שרה'])
net.add_edge('אברהם', 'שרה')
net.show('select.html')
```

The second case (filtering):

```
from pyvis.network import Network

net = Network(height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white",
                  filter_menu=True)
net.add_nodes(['אברהם', 'שרה'])
net.add_edge('אברהם', 'שרה')
net.show('filter.html')
```

The second case works as expected, while the first case displays the words as `????-???`
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this issue and display the UTF-8 characters in the selection menu as well?

BTW, on the GitHub project page, [I noted the problem](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/issues/173) as well.